# How to route all network traffic through tor

Tags: onion-routing, torsocks, transparent-proxy

I'm trying to create a network that sends all traffic through tor.

So far I've got a PFsense box acting as a router and a separate debian instance with tor installed and running.  Is there a way to get all my pfsense traffic to go through the tor socks proxy?

If not, is there another way to accomplish this?

I've tried the following but they don't work on current versions of pfsense.

https://www.malwaretech.com/2015/08/creating-ultimate-tor-virtual-network.html

https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-Set-Up-a-Tor-Proxy-Server-on-pfSense

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a more specific problem that you're running into. There are a lot of guides online about sending all traffic through tor, and hopefully someone here can help, but you'll probably get more help with a more specific question.

Comment: well, I actually am looking for a guide.  The ones I've found so far, don't work with any up to date router oses that I've found.